# Security issue, HMAC in header vs https, or both?

Tags: android, iphone, https, hmac

I'm setting up a server which an android app and an iPhone app will connect to. And I'm wondering what type of security is more secure for sending/requesting data?

Currently I generate a HMAC-SHA256 of the content I'm sending to the server in the header to verify its integrity. 
But I'm wondering if its more secure to use a https connection instead? If I use https, could I skip the HMAC?

I would like to know the differences in security, which is more secure?

And also, if I'm using either is it better to use both for an extra layer of security?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quick answer to your questions: SSL if used properly should give you more security guarantees than HMAC. So, usually SSL can be used in a way that removes the need for HMAC.

HMAC provides integrity as well as authenticity. Assuming the client and the server use pre-shared symmetric keys to calculate the HMACs, one side can be sure that the device on the other end has the secret key. This provides authenticity of both server and client.

What is missing in this picture (with just HMAC) is confidentiality. What is the nature of data exchanged between the server and client? Is there any sensitive user data being transferred during the communication that you don't want a man-in-the-middle to see? If so, then you may want to use SSL.

SSL gives you confidentiality (among other things). Meaning that you can be sure that you have a secured end-to-end connection and no man-in-the-middle can see what data is being exchanged between the server and client. However, common SSL usage does not include client machine authentication. Fro example, your web browser checks for Paypal's authenticity when you go to their https webpage. But the Paypal server does not ask your browser to send any certificate from your side.

Since you are comparing SSL with HMAC, I am assuming you care about authenticity of both sides. So, use SSL with both server and client authentication. This basically means that both of them would ask for each other's certificates and check different aspects of the certificates (i.e. common name, certificate issuer etc.). You can create your own certificate issuer to sign these certificates.

If you are making an app for AppStore or Google Play that users can simply install and start using, you may want to think through how the client side certificates will be generated, signed or who will sign them. You can remove the need for client side certificate (and signing) by adopting a model similar to [GitHub's](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), where the user manually informs the server of trusted public keys to authenticate devices. But you can probably see how this process might not be user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. Its exactly what I wanted to know. :)

Comment: Doesn't SSL use HMAC by default?